# Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'apply()'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Tengo un error que nunca tuve en al compilar en Android Studio.

> Error:(1, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'apply()' Possible causes:
>
> - The project 'Mas104.5' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file
> - The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

**\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**\app\build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android  {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.1.7'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "masproducciones.radiomas1045"
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisando tu configuración me parece que tu problema es el siguiente:

> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Revisa que todas las dependencias se encuentren únicamente en el build.gradle que se encuentra en  nivel de aplicación y asegura se encuentren las necesarias en tu proyecto:

```
\app\build.gradle
```

Comment: `dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}` esto esta en `\app\build.gradle` Decis que me puede estar faltando alguna dependencia?